# Configure a constant in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, image-uploading

I want to provide upload functionality in my website. I cannot save the uploaded image inside the war. I can save it to some particular location on my machine and refer it from there.
The problem is I have to make this code compatible to a Windows machine, a mac and Openshift server. So path for images folder will be different on different machines.

The workaround I was thinking is to somehow configure the images folder location in tomcat server on different machines and read it from there. Is there any way to configure a variable inside tomcat?
Also is there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can define environment variable in the context configuration file.

```
<Context>
    <Environment name="myapp.upload.dir" type="java.lang.String" value="/srv/app/upload" override="true" />
</Context>
```

You can either create a new context file just for your application or put the Environment entry in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml` in which case this property will be accessible to all applications running in your Tomcat instance. [Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Introduction) is Tomcat documentation about contexts.

To access the variable value you would then use following code:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();  
String uploadDir = (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/myapp.upload.dir");
```

**Option 2**

You could specify it as a JVM property in `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` (or `$TOMCAT_HOME\bin\setenv.bat` on Windows) and retrieve it like so:

```
System.getProperty("myapp.upload.dir");
```

Personally I think that the first solution is cleaner.

Also as a final note, I would not think of this solution as a workaround. It is perfectly acceptable solution to specify things like upload directory in some sort of configuration file rather than to have one fixed location which works for all platform but can't be changed (for example something like `$HOME/app/upload`).

Comment: I like your first and third solution. Before choosing first solution I would like to give third solution a try. Can you please tell me what will be value of $HOME on windows?

Comment: You could get that value from Java system properties (`System.getProperty("user.home")`). Complete list is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html. It includes properties like file separator for the platform your application is running on, so in theory you can construct platform universal path just from these properties.